# How to implement a recycleview to display multiple scrollable or fixed elements inside a cardview

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

[i want to do something similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNi8L.png)

I need advise or suggestion on how to do something like this on android studio 3.0.
I am building a food ordering app, and need to show an order summary.
I kinda did it but the food name, quantity, price eg.(Medium Pizza, 1 pcs, $6.8) does not show up.

I did it using two layouts, one has a recycle view  and the other has only a card view with food name, quantity, price eg.(Medium Pizza, 1 pcs, $6.8).
The one with the recycle view has a cardview showing order number ,order status on top and showing total on the bottom. So in between the top and the bottom i placed the recycle view so that it can show the food name, quantity, price eg(Medium Pizza, 1 pcs, $6.8).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@drawable/backgground"
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
tools:context="com.example.reds0n.foodorderclient.Cart">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardView2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp">


        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Order# 123957262"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:id="@+id/ordernumber"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
            android:textColor="@color/fbutton_color_green_sea"
            android:text="Status: Done" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
            android:textColor="@color/fbutton_color_green_sea"
            android:text=" Done" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/yellowish">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Total:"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pirce"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="100"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"/>

              </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

           </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/orderDetailsRecycle"
         android:layout_width="400dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/background_header" />

    </RelativeLayout> 





 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
mlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@color/black_overlay"
tools:context="com.example.reds0n.foodorderclient.orderDetails">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/ordernumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/fbutton_color_green_sea">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/foodname"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Big Burger "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemPcs"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="22Pcs"/>

          <TextView

              android:id="@+id/itemPrice"
              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
              android:text="$100"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

[My Display from the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM6iQ.png)

[This is one of the designs i 1st created but i don't like the way it repeats each food item in its own cardview..(Dont mind the the ugly design tho :) )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8unTv.png)

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZT7G.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not understand the what you are expecting. I assume you want to show the list of ordered items with details inside the card view.

Use Recyclerview which fill the screen, add the cardview with order details as the items.
Search for "Heteregenous RecyclerView Android" you will get lot of code sample to implement what you need.

Comment: Yhh i could do that but then each food item would be displayed in one card view.  I want just one card view that that would display all ordered foods. just like the 1st image.

Comment: If you want to use recyclerview you need to set height for recyclerview inside card view  to make it work.Otherwise use vertical linear layout and inflate row items and  dynamically add them